# Java regex Matcher.find() confusion

Tags: java, regex

I'm an experienced coder but a regex novice running Oracle's JDK 1.8 on Windows 10.

My code:

```
   private static void regex1() {
      Console con = System.console();
      String txt;
      Pattern pat = 
            Pattern.compile(con.readLine("Input a regular expression: "));
      while (true) {
         txt = con.readLine("\nInput a string: ");
         if (txt.isEmpty()) {
            break;
         }
         Matcher mch = pat.matcher(txt);
         if (mch.find()) {
            con.printf("That string matches\n");
            for (int grp = 0; grp <= mch.groupCount(); grp++) {
               con.printf("     Group %d matched  %s\n", 
                     grp, mch.group(grp));
            }
         }
         else {
            con.printf("That string does not match\n");
         }
      }
   }
```

A sample run:

```
Input a regular expression: ([a-zA-Z]*), ([a-zA-Z]*)
Pattern: '([a-zA-Z]*), ([a-zA-Z]*)'

Input a string: Doe, John
String: 'Doe, John'
That string matches
2 groups
     Group 0 matched  'Doe, John'
     Group 1 matched  'Doe'
     Group 2 matched  'John'

Input a string: Bond, 007
String: 'Bond, 007'
That string matches
2 groups
     Group 0 matched  'Bond, '
     Group 1 matched  'Bond'
     Group 2 matched  ''

Input a string: once again, stuff
String: 'once again, stuff'
That string matches
2 groups
     Group 0 matched  'again, stuff'
     Group 1 matched  'again'
     Group 2 matched  'stuff'

Input a string:
```

The first and third sets seem fine, but the "Bond, 007" response has me stumped.
The expression is a group of one or more alphas followed by a comma and a space followed by another group of one or more alphas.

The find() method seems to be returning true when it stumbles on the "007" and the group that it claims to have matched is a null string.

Am I missing something obvious here or just losing my mind?

TIA

Comment: `*` matches 0 or more instances. `+` matches 1 or more.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error. I stared at this for some time and must have read right past those asterisks a dozen times.  Yes, pluses work much better for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Following [documentation of the find() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), we can see that it will:

```
Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
```

In the case where you input `Bond, 0007`, your regex will match:

- Capture group 0 (the whole match): `Bond,`
- Capture group 1 (the first part between `()`'s (`([a-zA-Z]*)`): `Bond`
- Capture group 2 (the second part between `()`'s (`([a-zA-Z]*)`): Empty string

I'm suspecting that your confusion either comes from `find()` not matching the entire input (if you want this, then you should use [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) instead), or you might be confused by `*` being able to match zero occurrences of the part it applies to (opposed to `+`, which must match at least once).